# Prevent clicking an anchor link while an input is focused?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm attempting to prevent a user from clicking a link and it going to another page while any input is focused. Sometimes the only available space around the input and the keyboard is a link and some users click the link accidentally. I'm trying to make it so when they click the link it blurs the input (closes the keyboard) and prevents the page from following the link. Then let them click the link again if they want to go to another page after the input is no longer in focus.

**html**

```
<input type="text">
<a href="example.com">Example</a>
```

I've tried the following...

**jQuery**

```
$('a').on('click', function (event) {
   if ($('input').is(":focus")) {
      console.log('focused');
      event.preventDefault();
   }
});
```

(nothing gets logged)

Also tried this...

```
if ($('input').is(":focus")) {
    $('a').on('click', function (event) {
      event.preventDefault();
      $('input').each(function(){
        $(this).trigger('blur');
      });
    });
  }
```

Neither one prevent the page from going to whatever link was clicked...

Comment: `blur` will be done before the click starts registering

Comment: "Sometimes the only available space around the input and the keyboard is a link and some users click the link accidentally" It seems like you're trying to solve a design problem with code. Consider changing the design instead.

Comment: Not possible to redesign in this case. It's a problem on really small screens since the keyboard takes up so much space and the input is fixed at the top and must be. Looking for an actual solution.

Comment: Fix it with media query css

Comment: Your problem is circular. How are you to distinguish between a valid click of the link (which blurs the input and triggers click on the link) and an accidental click of a link?

Comment: @charlietfl  you are always right. Thanks so much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think you can do this. You can disable the `click` event on the links while `input` is focused, and enable it back again when `blur` occurs on the `input` elements. However, while if user clicks on a link while focused on the `input` element `blur` event will occur first (which would enable clicking) then `click` even occurs and links acts as normal.

You could try disabling the links while `input` elements have focus, then you can enable them on the first click and restore normal operation.

```js
$("input").on("focus", function() {
    $("a").on("click", function (event) {
      event.preventDefault();
      $("a").off();
    });
  
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" />
<a href="http://example.com/">example</a>
```

Comment: Ohh this works too! This is exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

I think I found a solution.

**HTML**

Example.com

**jQuery**

```
$('input').on('focus', function () {
      $('a').each(function(){
        $(this).addClass('cant-click');
      });
});

$(document).on('touchend', function (e) {
    if (!$(e.target).closest('input').length) {
      $('a').each(function(){
        $(this).removeClass('cant-click');
      });
    }
});
```

**CSS**

```
a.cant-click { pointer-events: none; }
```

When the input takes focus, every link gets this class. When anything on the page is clicked that is not an input, it removes this class from every link.